# To stop a process in Matlab with Dvorak keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, dvorak

The keybing **CMD-C** and **CMD-point** work in Qwerty keybinding in OSX's Matlab, but not with Dvorak keybinding in OSX's Matlab.
There must be a bug in Matlab, which is causing this.

The problem is that when I push press play button for an algorithm in while loop. 
Many times, I want to stop it before the while-loop end.

The code below is not a low-level code since it can be stopped with Qwerty keyboard layout.

> **How can you stop process in OSX Matlab with Dvorak keyboard layout?**

**Example of the function that I am trying to stop**

```
while 1;
     3
end
```

Comment: See my updated answer, CTRL-C visually and C is hardcoded to a specific key not changed when layout changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matlab's hardcoded CTRL-C combo**

It is not CMD-C, it is CTRL-C VISUALLY. So press CTRL-C as written on your keyboard, not the C on Dvorak layout or any other layout. Matlab has hardcoded the interruption command to a key, not a letter.

**Debugging**

The way I do it is to create breakpoint with the looping vars

```
for ii=1...10000
     if isequal(ii,2000)  
         %Add here a breakpoint
     end
     ...
end
```

where the breakpoints make it possible to stop the execution. Also force-quiting Matlab is the other way. I know no other way to them.

Comment: This works! CTRL-C visually.

Comment: For those with physical Dvorak keyboards, if Ctrl+C doesn’t work, try Ctrl+J.

Answer (score 1):

It is `CTRL-C`, but `Command-period` works as well. If you have tried this 
and it's not working you are probably trying to interrupt a function 
that isn't interruptible. You can't interrupt a low-level function 
call, such as a big matrix multiply or backslash or something like that.

Comment: These commands work if you are using Qwery keyboard layout, but not with Dvorak keyboard layout that I am using. I tried also to press the Qwerty position of the keys unsuccessfully. So Matlab is messing something with different keyboard layouts.